# Haxe: Crash when build to android target

Tags: java, android, haxe

I am new to **Haxe**. Today I install it by reading the instructions in the http://www.haxenme.org;

and download the "Acurate Example".

I run the example with FalshDevelop, when I build it to flash(`nme test "Acurate Example.nmml" flash`), it goes well!
But when I use `nme test "Acurate Example.nmml" android`, it crashes!!

I have setting the android variables ok.

Please help me, thanks in advance!

PS: Errors here:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Neusoft\桌面\11yue\HaXe\Demos\Actuate_Example>nme test
 "Actuate Example.nmml" android
haxelib run hxcpp Build.xml haxe -Dactuate -Dandroid -Dcpp -Dhaxe_208 -Dmobile -
Dnme -Dnme_install_tool -Dtrue
mkdir obj/android
mkdir obj/android/src
mkdir obj/android/src/nme
mkdir obj/android/src/nme/display
mkdir obj/android/src/nme/events
mkdir obj/android/src/nme/geom
mkdir obj/android/src/nme/text
mkdir obj/android/src/nme/errors
mkdir obj/android/src/nme/utils
mkdir obj/android/src/com
mkdir obj/android/src/com/eclecticdesignstudio
mkdir obj/android/src/com/eclecticdesignstudio/motion
mkdir obj/android/src/com/eclecticdesignstudio/motion/actuators
mkdir obj/android/src/haxe
mkdir obj/android/src/haxe/io
mkdir obj/android/src/nme/media
mkdir obj/android/src/cpp
mkdir obj/android/src/com/eclecticdesignstudio/motion/easing
mkdir obj/android/src/cpp/zip
mkdir obj/android/src/nme/filters
mkdir obj/android/src/cpp/rtti
mkdir obj/android/src/nme/net
mkdir obj/android/src/nme/installer
mkdir obj/android/src/cpp/io
mkdir obj/android/src/com/eclecticdesignstudio/motion/_Actuate
mkdir obj/android/src/cpp/io/_Process
mkdir obj/android/__pch
mkdir obj/android/__pch/haxe
Creating obj/android/__pch/haxe/hxcpp.h.gch...
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -Iinclude --sysroot=D:/AndroidDev/android-ndk-r5/platf
orms/android-5/arch-arm -ID:/AndroidDev/android-ndk-r5/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libst
dc++/4.4.3/include -ID:/AndroidDev/android-ndk-r5/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/
4.4.3/libs/armeabi/include -ID:\HaXe_ProgramFiles\Motion-Twin\haxe\lib\hxcpp\2,0
8,1//include -Iinclude -fpic -fvisibility=hidden -ffunction-sections -funwind-ta
bles -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__A
RM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D_LINUX_STDDEF_H  -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mt
une=xscale -msoft-float -fomit-frame-pointer -fexceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -
finline-limit=10000 -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -O2 -DNDEBUG -c -frtti -o obj/an
droid/__pch/haxe/hxcpp.h.gch D:\HaXe_ProgramFiles\Motion-Twin\haxe\lib\hxcpp\2,0
8,1//include/hxcpp.h
Called from ? line 1
Called from BuildTool.hx line 1342
Called from BuildTool.hx line 591
Called from BuildTool.hx line 626
Called from BuildTool.hx line 760
Called from BuildTool.hx line 791
Called from BuildTool.hx line 174
Uncaught exception - Error creating pch: 1 - build cancelled
Error : Build failed
```

And It popup a Error dialog with message:

> cc1plus.exe-error;Application cannot normally initiate(0xc0000005).

Answer (score 1):

Could you try testing the Pirate Pig sample, to see if that compiles alright?

Comment: @Joshua Granick yeah, I have tried some projects, but the same crash occured. I have checked the buildTool.hx and build xmls, I hope the author can make a more easy to config android environment version. Well, stability is  most important! Thanks!